# debug xv6 code with gdb failed to reading symbol table

Tags: debugging, operating-system, gdb, xv6

I'm having trouble using the qemu-gdb. I executed `make qemu-gdb` in one tab and `riscv64-unknown-elf-gdb` in another tab.  Then I get this:

```
riscv64-unknown-elf-gdb kernel/kernel
GNU gdb (GDB) 10.1
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
Type "show copying" and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "--host=x86_64-apple-darwin21.5.0 --target=riscv64-unknown-elf".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
    <http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.

For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
/Users/username/.gdbinit:1: Error in sourced command file:
No symbol table is loaded.  Use the "file" command.
Reading symbols from kernel/kernel...
warning: File "/Users/username/cs_study/os/6S081/labs/xv6-labs-2022/.gdbinit" auto-loading has been declined by your `auto-load safe-path' set to "$debugdir:$datadir/auto-load".
To enable execution of this file add
    add-auto-load-safe-path /Users/username/cs_study/os/6S081/labs/xv6-labs-2022/.gdbinit
line to your configuration file "/Users/username/.gdbinit".
To completely disable this security protection add
    set auto-load safe-path /
line to your configuration file "/Users/username/.gdbinit".
For more information about this security protection see the
"Auto-loading safe path" section in the GDB manual.  E.g., run from the shell:
    info "(gdb)Auto-loading safe path
```

According to the prompt, I add the line `add-auto-load-safe-path /Users/username/cs_study/os/6S081/labs/xv6-labs-2022/.gdbinit` in the file `/Users/username/.gdbinit`. When I execute `source /Users/username/.gdbinit`, it prompts `command not found: add-auto-load-safe-path`.
Then I add the line `set auto-load safe-path /` to the file and source it. But I get the same result when I run the `riscv64-unknown-elf-gdb`. The content of the `/Users/username/.gdbinit`:

```
set startup-with-shell off
set auto-load safe-path /
add-auto-load-safe-path /Users/username/cs_study/os/6S081/labs/xv6-labs-2022/.gdbinit
```

And when I typed `riscv64-unknown-elf-gdb`, it shows the same result as above, then I typed `source .gdbinit` in GDB, it shows

````
riscv64-unknown-elf-gdb kernel/kernel
GNU gdb (GDB) 10.1
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
Type "show copying" and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "--host=x86_64-apple-darwin21.5.0 --target=riscv64-unknown-elf".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
    <http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.

For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
/Users/username/.gdbinit:1: Error in sourced command file:
No symbol table is loaded.  Use the "file" command.
Reading symbols from kernel/kernel...
warning: File "/Users/username/cs_study/os/6S081/labs/xv6-labs-2022/.gdbinit" auto-loading has been declined by your `auto-load safe-path' set to "$debugdir:$datadir/auto-load".
To enable execution of this file add
    add-auto-load-safe-path /Users/username/cs_study/os/6S081/labs/xv6-labs-2022/.gdbinit
line to your configuration file "/Users/username/.gdbinit".
To completely disable this security protection add
    set auto-load safe-path /
line to your configuration file "/Users/username/.gdbinit".
For more information about this security protection see the
"Auto-loading safe path" section in the GDB manual.  E.g., run from the shell:
    info "(gdb)Auto-loading safe path"
(gdb) source .gdbinit
The target architecture is set to "riscv:rv64".```
````

Comment: That's odd, because as far as I can tell `command not found` is not how GDB reports unknown commands -- you'd expect to see `Undefined command:` instead.  Crazy question, but you are sourcing the `.gdbinit` inside GDB, right?

Comment: I executed the command `source /Users/username/.gdbinit` in the terminal not in GDB, for it prompts that add the line to file `"/Users/username/.gdbinit"`.  After I executed `source .gdbinit` in GDB, it prompts `The target architecture is set to "riscv:rv64". It seems that the symbol table is still not read and I do not know how to load it.

Comment: You're going to need to update your question with current GDB output though I suspect this error: `/Users/lichenglong/.gdbinit:1: Error in sourced command file: ...` might still be an issue.  Try sharing that file and/or addressing that error.

Comment: Updated. Please have a look and tell me which information do you need

Comment: It took me a while to realise, but these two lines are related:
`/Users/username/.gdbinit:1: Error in sourced command file:
No symbol table is loaded.  Use the "file" command.` Which indicates that the command on line 1 of the `.gdbinit` is triggering the `No symbol table is loaded` error.  However, the file contents as shown in your questions are fine ... did you do an exact copy&paste from that file?  Or retype them?  Double check the the actual file contents are spelt correctly as a typo would trigger the error you are seeing.

Comment: The first line `set startup-with-shell off` in .gdbinit existed when I opened the file `.gdbinit`. I copied the line`add-auto-load-safe-path /Users/username/cs_study/os/6S081/labs/xv6-labs-2022/.gdbinit` to the file and then executed `source /User/username/.gdbinit` in the shell according to the prompt, but it told me `/Users/username/.gdbinit:2: command not found: add-auto-load-safe-path `. Then I copied the line `set auto-load safe-path /` to the `.gdbinit` file, and sourced it again, it prompted `set auto-load safe-path /`.